# no metro style templates in VS2012 ultimate on windows 8

Tags: templates, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I have a VM with windows 8 x64 bit and I installed VS2012 ultimate from microsoft webiste. It prompted me for the developer license - I clicked ok. It asked me to signin to microsoft account. I created one and signed it and it worked. but when I try to create new project, I didnt see any metro style app templates.
I tried uninstall and install again but no progress.
please help. I dont see the metro style folder in project templates \csharp.
when I downloaded http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247147 it went close, I saw the metro style folder in templates but the installation threw error at the end - iis8 install error and vs did not open either.

Comment: There are no metro style apps. Are you referring to Windows Store apps?

Comment: The templates formerly named "Metro Style" are now named "Windows Store."

Answer (score 2):

What was previously referred to as a "metro" template, is now the "Windows Store App" template.

Comment: yup - I finally just figured that Windows Store apps is what I was looking for. didnt know it was renamed and tore my hair apart. Thanks much